# With Chromium-based browsers, how to force-open an HTTP version of the site if HTTPS is also available?

Tags: google-chrome, http, chromium, opera, vivaldi

Consider I want to open a website and force HTTP, even if an HTTPS version is available. For example, I want to browse http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/ (HTTP), because the HTTPS version

1. presents an invalid SSL certificate (either expired or with a wrong server name, resulting in all kinds of `NET::ERR_CERT_*_INVALID` errors), because the server is a part of a CDN, and
2. my HTTPS request would lead to HTTP 404 anyway, since the HTTPS version of the site serves a different content (there's no `/merged/dists`).

Yes, technically, what has been described above is a site misconfiguration.

And yes, I'm aware that browsing an HTTP site would be equally insecure as browsing an HTTPS site with an invalid certificate.

Yet, I'm in control of my own freedom with *Mozilla*-based and console browsers (`lynx` & friends), and apparently, *Chromium* and derivatives just tie my hands. For the greater good, of course.

[image]

Here's what happens under the hood.

Whenever a browser sends out an HTTP request, it also add the

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

header, resulting in HTTP servers almost always upgrading the connection to HTTPS by responding with `HTTP 307`. I haven't found any way to disable this but to strip the header on the proxy server side (*Squid*):

```
request_header_access Upgrade-Insecure-Requests deny all
```

Still, this only helps with Debian-branded *Chromium*, while Chrome, Opera, and Vivaldi keep misbehaving. Safe browsing and DNS over HTTPS are turned off where possible:

[image]

Running *Wireshark* on the proxy server side reveals that there're multiple TLS requests to `*.1e100.net` (the Google network) and `*.checkdomain.de` domains, and it's not possible to prevent those on the DNS server side: probably, the IP addresses of the `*.1e100.net` network are "baked" in the Chromium codebase.

Further examination of the proxy server traffic shows that **no connection is even made** to the target site (`deb.devuan.org`), because the browser (or any of the Google services it uses) somehow knows that the website I'm requesting **can** serve HTTPS, and forces HTTPS connection regardless of the actual protocol in the URL.

Here's the fragment of the proxy's `access.log` for *Chromium* (the good):

```
1634306345.046     62 192.168.0.30 TCP_MISS/200 998 GET http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/ - HIER_DIRECT/95.216.15.86 text/html
```

And here's what I see for *Chrome* (the bad) and *Opera* (the ugly), respectively:

```
1634306270.092     55 192.168.0.30 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4584 CONNECT deb.devuan.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/95.216.15.86 -
```

```
1634306169.040     51 192.168.0.30 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4584 CONNECT deb.devuan.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/95.216.15.86 -
1634306169.086     44 192.168.0.30 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4584 CONNECT deb.devuan.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/95.216.15.86 -
1634306169.100     54 192.168.0.30 TCP_MISS/204 196 GET http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204 - HIER_DIRECT/173.194.222.94 -
1634306169.131     44 192.168.0.30 TCP_TUNNEL/200 4584 CONNECT deb.devuan.org:443 - HIER_DIRECT/95.216.15.86 -
```

Furthermore, if I prohibit HTTPS traffic entirely (on the proxy server), it still wouldn't be possible to open an HTTP version of the site, either. The browser will fail with an `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` error (for plain HTTP) -- and that's not because it failed to connect to `deb.devuan.org:443`. No, it's because it tried to phone back home (to Google) and failed.

Any ideas on how I can re-enable HTTP in my web browsers?

Versions tested:

- *Chrome*: **93.0.4577.63**
- *Opera*: **78.0.4093.184**
- *Vivaldi*: **4.1.2369.21**

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=force+http & https://superuser.com/questions/1035711/can-i-force-https-requests-to-use-http

Comment: @spikey_richie No. My question is about a particular browser engine that doesn't respect its users.

Comment: Google Chromium forces HTTPS becaus you visited devuan.org in the past, and they serve an header saying all subdomains MUST be accessed over HTTPS only, if you use firefox to visit the rt domain, you see it also upgrades the connection to HTTPS as requested by the side. Note the HSTS part of the error message

Comment: This is not possible any more. Even deleting the HSTS info in chrome://net-internals/#hsts doesn't work.

Comment: devuan.org with includeSubdomains is on the preload list -- which Firefox claims to also use, but it is NOT forced to https in my 78.15esr. And the server I reach at that name (with openssl) not only gives a cert that is for (only) `DNS:ftp.fau.de, DNS:ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de, DNS:ftp.uni-erlangen.de` but does NOT include `Strict-Transport-Security`, and to get ON preload you must be serving STS, so clearly the server has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to open a website and force HTTP, even if an HTTPS version is available.

The simplest solution is probably to use a browser that doesn't enforce HTTPS (e.g. "lynx & friends"). If you want something Chromium-based and available for Windows and Linux, I might suggest considering [Ungoogled Chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) (version 92 or earlier). Build files for Debian are currently available [here](https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-debian).

> I want to browse e.g. http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/

Ungoogled Chromium 92 or earlier will not force HTTPS on this site. Note, however, if you have visited the HTTPS version in the past, caching can still come into play (so in some cases, you may need to explicitly use `http://` or clear your cache).

Of course, be aware that an HTTP version of a site may not exist, and/or the web server may still try to redirect you to HTTPS (not the browser itself initially).

> Any ideas on how I can re-enable HTTP in my web browsers?

As already indicated, use a browser that doesn't have these requirements.

Comment: "Strip out the offending code" I don't recommend stripping out HSTS support, it is designed to make sure the control is with the website if HTTP must be avoided, you loose a lot more security than you think you will do, and your advice is dangerous

Comment: @Ferrybig Sometimes the inegrity of the content served by a pure HTTP server can be verified by some other means (as is with Debian repositories). In this case, I need a generic HTTP client, and a modern browser can no longer be used as a generic HTTP client. Freedom and security have always been inverse proportional. I, personally, would choose a tool which allowed me to select the level of security for each particular task. Remember network "zones" in MSIE (local computer, LAN, Internet, Trusted Sites)? While poorly implemented, this was actually the right idea.

Comment: @Bass My sincere apologies. Unfortunately, I've had to update my answer (which is essentially the same advice -- use another browser). However, poking around it appears that the most recent versions of Ungoogled Chromium have fallen prey to the problem your are attempting to avoid. That is, you need to use Ungoogled Chromium version 92 or earlier (released 08-21-21), as versions 93 and 94 now have the same issue.  This was entirely my fault -- I thought I had updated Ungoogled Chromium more recently than that.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, many thanks for yor answer as well as for the correction.